# What does Python max() do if it takes two lists in it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How come max([1,2,3], [1,1,4]) returns [1,2,3] not [1,1,4]?

I was asked this question in a class. I don't understand why it returns [1,2,3] and the logic behind it (even if it returns [1,1,4], I still don't understand what max() function does).

Comment: Because the lists are compared left to right and 2>1; Try `max([1,2,3], [1,1,4], key=max)` to get the other behavior you are expecting.

Comment: `[1,2,3] > [1,1,4]` because `2 > 1`.

Answer (score 0):

The function `max` will succeed in outputing a maximum as long as the provided arguments are comparable.

In this case, the first argument is greater than the second with regard to list-ordering.

```
>>> [1, 2, 3] > [1, 1, 4]
True
```